# Facebook like box cut off in Chrome

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

It is working fine in Firefox, but not in chrome I used firebug and found the default css height is causing this problem. How can I fix this?

It is using ITP Share Module in Joomla 2.5, have tried overflow: visible but its not helping.

[image: Facebook like box cut off in Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your css to solve this.

put the facebook share module in a div with a unique class or id.

example:

```
  <div id="FacebookShareContainer"><!--put here the plugin in your html page--></div>
```

then:

in you css file:

```
  #FacebookShareContainer span{
  height:19px;
}
#FacebookShareContainer iframe{
  height:19px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the zoom on your browser - the Facebook like button will appear this way when slightly zoomed out.

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur - especially in mobile testing mode I've found - if just the iFrame for Facebook is zoomed in.

You need to tab to highlight the Facebook button (like / login / share) and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to zoom as needed. Going to Facebook.com in another window and zooming doesn't always seem to fix this.

Same can happen with other iframes, such as Paypal button :

[image]